# Unwanted outlined appearing for a UIBezierPath that is filled and used as a clip for a see thru gradient

Tags: ios, gradient, uibezierpath, antialiasing

I have a path that is filled and also used for a clip to provide a gradient. The rendering of the gradient is just a tiny bit smaller or differently anti-aliased compared with the rendering of the fill. This creates an outline effect:

[image: image of a leaf shape with a light yellow to gray gradient, surrounded by a darker grey jagged outline]

Is there any way to remove this outline?

Note that:

1. Using two separately drawn identical paths does not solve the problem
2. Using no fill, but two gradients instead does not solve the problem. Even with just a gradient over another gradient, you get the outline.
3. It is possible to get the gradient I want without the outline by using just a solid gradient with no fill, but that makes animating the effects of the gradient more difficult later.

Here is the code:

```
let path4Path = UIBezierPath()
//ordinary drawing stuff here
path4Path.close()
fillColor.setFill()  //set to black fill
path4Path.fill()
context.saveGState()
context.setAlpha(0.9)
path4Path.addClip()
context.drawLinearGradient(allToldGradient, start: CGPoint(x: 52.72, y: 114.48), end: CGPoint(x: 30.22, y: 91.99), options: [])
context.restoreGState()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to turn off antialiasing like this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, NO);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationNone);
```

Comment: Please write your answer in english

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and come back to mark the answer correct if it works.